# Trying to install Rails 3, getting a strange "Ruby upgrade" notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

I'm trying to get my computer (Mac OS X, running Leopard) running with the latest version of Rails. Before this, I had 2.3.5. I tried following some instructions a few days ago, but didn't seem to make much progress. Now, I can't do *anything* in Rails. You'll see what I mean in a sec.

**Theoretically, I've got the latest versions of Ruby:**

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin9]

$ sudo ruby -v
Password:
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin9]
```

**But if I try to run Rails, I get this error message:**

```
$ rails testapp03
Rails requires Ruby version 1.8.7 or later.
You're running 1.8.6 (2008-08-11); please upgrade to continue.
```

**And if I try to see which version of Rails I'm using, I get the same:**

```
$ rails -v
Rails requires Ruby version 1.8.7 or later.
You're running 1.8.6 (2008-08-11); please upgrade to continue.
```

In case these are useful:

```
$ which ruby
/opt/local/bin/ruby

$ sudo which ruby
Password:
/opt/local/bin/ruby

$ which rails
/usr/bin/rails
```

So, the question: **What have I done, and what do I need to do to get Ruby / RubyGems / Rails up and running on my computer?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing this command `/opt/local/bin/ruby -v` from the command line and see what version of ruby that come out.

Next find out where is the ruby gems is located with `whereis ruby`. I assume it should near `/opt/local/lib/ruby-x.x/gems/...`. Also try find out whether rails is installed under those directories. If not, your rails might be still pointing to the old ruby.

Also check if you have /usr/bin/ruby? If so, what is the output of /usr/bin/ruby -v ?
If it exists and rails is pointing to that version, So you should uninstall that ruby and rails, and install the rails gem all over again with /opt/local/bin/ruby

Comment: $ /opt/local/bin/ruby -v ... yields ... ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin9]

 ... 

$ whereis ruby ... yields ... /usr/bin/ruby


So, if I'm understanding your point, both Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3 (and RubyGems 1.3.5) should all be in the same directory?

Comment: I suspect so. Do you have `/usr/bin/ruby` ? If so, what is the output of `/usr/bin/ruby -v` ?

Comment: Ah. This output: ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [universal-darwin9.0] ... a friend suggested I remove Rails and then try to reinstall it, with the idea being that then reinstalling it would hopefully put Rails in opt/local/bin. Is removing the system version of Rails problematic?

Comment: So you should uninstall that ruby and rails, and install the `rails gem` all over again with `/opt/local/bin/ruby`. Cheers.

Comment: I thought I had it, but I'm hitting a new problem.

I can create a new rails app, but if I try to run script/server, I get a strange message: ...

    applications $ cd testapp05 ... 
    testapp05 $ script/server ... 
    /Users/Park/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/http11.bundle: [BUG] Bus Error ... 
    ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i686-darwin9] ... 
    
    Abort trap ... 
    testapp05 $ script/server ... 

Any idea what that's referring to? I've never seen a "Bus Error" before. (???)

Comment: The error is from your mongrel. Try uninstalling mongrel gem and live with webrick for the time being.

Comment: This remedied the issue, although I soon ran into some others, so I ended up going with RVM, using the tutorial here: http://pivotallabs.com/users/jsusser/blog/articles/1173-spiking-on-a-rails-3-upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

What does `which gem` return?

Probably, your Ruby installation points to `/opt/local/bin/` while the gem command is still referencing `/usr/bin/`.
When you installed the Gem, the Gem was saved in `/usr/bin/` and loads the original system Ruby.

I don't know how you installed Ruby 1.8.7, however I would suggest you to take a step further: remove all your Ruby versions (except the system one, of course) and try [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/).

Comment: $ which gem
    /opt/local/bin/gem


I might go ahead and try RVM. I know Ryan Bates was endorsing it in his latest Railscast. (I'm sorry if this is a dumb question: How do I remove all of my ruby versions? Just delete the folders?)

Comment: Simone, thanks for that initial recommendation to go with RVM. I used the tutorial here: http://pivotallabs.com/users/jsusser/blog/articles/1173-spiking-on-a-rails-3-upgrade">this tutorial ... and it seems to be working. We'll see how it goes.